# How to customize the JSON schema hover?

Tags: monaco-editor

Using monaco-editor v0.14.3, we have set up a JSON editor, based on a JSON schema, like this:

```
monaco.languages.json.jsonDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions(
{
  validate: true,
  allowComments: true,
  schemas:
    [
      {
        uri: "https://server/schema.json",
        fileMatch: ["*.json"],
        schema: schema
      }]
});
```

where `schema` is a JSON schema object, for which the `description` property is defined for every property in the schema. This `description` property contains some HTML tags, and when hovering the JSON editor, this `description` is shown without interpreting the HTML tags, which displays something like "This property <b>defines</b> the way…".

We have looked in the direction of the `monaco.languages.registerHoverProvider()` method, in order to provide the hover text ourselves, but cannot access to the default hover mechanism, which computes the default JSON schema property, so as to customize it and turn the HTML into Markdown: is it possible to access to the `description` in the JSON schema related to the hovered text?

In addition, when modifying the JSON schema `description` property by using Markdown or HTML, the built-in hovering keeps on interpreting this field as raw text: is it possible to force the default hovering system to interpret in as Markdown or HTML?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [the guys from Monaco](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1816#issuecomment-584211685), there is an undocumented property named `markdownDescription` which the JSON language service uses instead of the `description`. This isn't standard, but it works.

Comment: Too bad, however, that HTML content cannot be used…

Comment: good to know it works in monaco as well! this is documented for the language servers here at least:
https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/json#_use-rich-formatting-in-hovers

@ÉdouardMercier the `markdownDescription` field accepts a healthy subset of HTML tags btw!

Answer (score 0):

I customised the auto-suggest and validation in [@monaco-editor/react](https://github.com/suren-atoyan/monaco-react) by setting the schema in a function passed to `onMount`:

```js
import React from "react"
import Editor from "@monaco-editor/react"

const CodeEditor = (props) => {
  function onMount(editor, monaco) {
    const modelUri = "foo://myapp/custom.json"
    const model = monaco.editor.createModel(
      `{ "type": "unknown" }`, "json", monaco.Uri.parse(modelUri)
    )
    editor.setModel(model)

    monaco.languages.json.jsonDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
      ...monaco.languages.json.jsonDefaults.diagnosticOptions,
      allowComments: true,
      schemas: [
        {
          uri: "foo://myapp/segment/type",
          fileMatch: ["*.json"],
          schema: {
            type: "object",
            properties: {
              type: {
                enum: ["v1", "v2"],
              }
            },
          },
        }
      ],
      validate: true
    })
  }

  return (
    <Editor language="json" onMount={onMount} />
  )
}

export default CodeEditor
```

Credit to [this GH issue](https://github.com/suren-atoyan/monaco-react/issues/69#issuecomment-612816117) that alluded to the solution.